# Finding maximum of function with additional information

Tags: r, string, max

Let's consider very easy function following :

```
easy_function=function(vec,string){
  if (string=='some_string') sum(vec)
  else if (string=='string_some') 3*max(vec)
  else if (string=='some_string_some') mean(sum(vec),max(vec))
}
```

what I want to do is to create another function `find_biggest<-function(vec)` which goes through all possible strings in `easy_function()` and returns list with objects :

(1) string for which maximum is reached

(2) value of maximum.

**My work so far**
It's very easy to obtain second point. Just like the following :

```
find_biggest<-function(vec){
  max(easy_function(vec,'some_string'),easy_function(vec,'string_some'),
      easy_function(vec,'some_string_some'))
}
```

However, I have no idea, how can I obtain for which string, maximum was reached. Could you help me getting so ?

For example `find_biggest(1:3)` should return list with objects :

(1) 'string_some' (it's the string for which maximum is reached)

(2) 9 (it's the maximum)

Comment: It would help if you could provide a short example with input and desired ouput.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I just update my question ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)

easy_function=function(vec,string){
  if (string=='some_string') sum(vec)
  else if (string=='string_some') 3*max(vec)
  else if (string=='some_string_some') mean(sum(vec),max(vec))
}

find_biggest <- function(vec){
  strings <- c("some_string", "string_some", "some_string_some")
  
  all_vals <- strings %>% map(easy_function, vec = vec) %>% unlist
  
  list(max_string = strings[which.max(all_vals)],
       max_val = max(all_vals))
}

find_biggest(1:10)
```